# Change fontweight of a selected text in a textblock WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I am trying to change the fontweight of a selected piece of text in a textbox. I would have thought **TextBoxVoorbeeld.SelectedText.FontWeight** would work but it doesn't below my code. This is a WPF application

```
private void Bold_On_Off()
    {
        if (TextBoxVoorbeeld.FontWeight == FontWeights.Normal)
        {
            TextBoxVoorbeeld.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            Bold.IsChecked = true;
            BoldButton.IsChecked = true;
            StatusBold.Content = "Bold";

        }
        else
        {
            TextBoxVoorbeeld.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            Bold.IsChecked = false;
            BoldButton.IsChecked = false;
            StatusBold.Content = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use RichTextbox for that ..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: Ok thx I'll look into it

Comment: This still doens't fix the problem it am able to grasp the selected text but the grasped text type does not understand the .Fontweight type so it is not compatible and hence it cannot be changed this way

Comment: @PIETERBRACKE is your problem solved or are you still in it??

Comment: Do you mean TextBlock or TextBox?